# add entry in hashtable from string in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, hashtable

I have a string like this, retrieved from a txt file:

```
$txtindex = 5
$PRINTERNAME = get-content $txtPrinterfile | select -Index $txtindex
$PRINTERNAME = $PRINTERNAME.Trim()
$PRINTERNAME = $PRINTERNAME.Replace(" ","")

$Printername
NAME="W018"
```

So I thought I could easily add this to a hashtable:

```
$HashPrinter = @{}
$HashPrinter.Add($PRINTERNAME)
```

but this is not working.

Either this:

```
$HashPrinter = @{$PRINTERNAME}
```

If I type it manually:

```
$HashPrinter = @{NAME="W018"}
```

it works as expected.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: A Hashtable keeps entries with a Name and a Value. In your manual example you provide both the name and the value, so that works. As for the other code, you are only trying to add a Value to the hash **without** the Name so that won't do.

Comment: The txt file already has the necessary syntax for adding an entry with Name and Value: Name="W018" So my idea was to put this into a variable and add it into the hashtable, as I don't see a difference between this and the manual example.

Comment: The difference is that from your text file, the value is just **one** string. When adding to a Hashtable you need to give it **two** params: `$HashPrinter.Add("Name", $PRINTERNAME)`. You can do that if you split the input from the text file in two variables first: `$name, $value = $PRINTERNAME -split '='` and then add like `$HashPrinter.Add($name, $value)`

Comment: Ok, I think I got you. I stumbled because when I type it manually, it looks like the "=" is recognized as a separator between name and value, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PS C:\Users\alHaos> $HashTable = @{}
PS C:\Users\alHaos> $HashTable.Add("Name", "Pr001")
PS C:\Users\alHaos> $HashTable.Add("Manufacture", "Epson")
PS C:\Users\alHaos> $HashTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Name                           Pr001
Manufacture                    Epson
```

Comment: As The comment of Theo and this answer here are similar, I followed this solution and split up the string variable $Printername into NAME and VALUE and added it into the hashtable as shown above.